# PySpark - merge two DataFrames, overwriting one with the other

Tags: dataframe, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I'm trying to figure out an efficient way to merge two PySpark DataFrames like this:

```
from pyspark.sql import Row
data = [Row(id=index, value=val, calc=val*2) for index, val in enumerate(range(10))]
df = spark.createDataFrame(data=data, schema=["id", "value", "calc"])
data2 = [Row(id=index, value=val, calc=val**2) for index, val in [(9, 9), (10, 10)]]
df2 = spark.createDataFrame(data=data2, schema=["id", "value", "calc"])


df.head(10)
# Outputs: [Row(id=0, value=0, calc=0), Row(id=1, value=1, calc=2), Row(id=2, value=2, calc=4), Row(id=3, value=3, calc=6), Row(id=4, value=4, calc=8), Row(id=5, value=5, calc=10), Row(id=6, value=6, calc=12), Row(id=7, value=7, calc=14), Row(id=8, value=8, calc=16), Row(id=9, value=9, calc=18)]

df2.head(2)
# Outputs: [Row(id=9, value=9, calc=81), Row(id=10, value=10, calc=100)]

df3 = SOME_MERGE_FUNCTION(df, df2)
df3.head(20)

# Outputs: [Row(id=0, value=0, calc=0), Row(id=1, value=1, calc=2), Row(id=2, value=2, calc=4), Row(id=3, value=3, calc=6), Row(id=4, value=4, calc=8), Row(id=5, value=5, calc=10), Row(id=6, value=6, calc=12), Row(id=7, value=7, calc=14), Row(id=8, value=8, calc=16), Row(id=9, value=9, calc=81), Row(id=10, value=10, calc=100)]
```

So how do I write `SOME_MERGE_FUNCTION()`?

Comment: Try `df2.unionAll(df3)`

Comment: @DKNY That is close, except that it creates duplicates where ids match (e.g. `Row(id=9, value=9, calc=18), Row(id=9, value=9, calc=81)`).

Comment: Try `df2.union(df3)`. Essentially, `unionAll` is used to keep the duplicate values and `union` just removes the duplicates and will return distinct entries.

Comment: in pyspark `union` and `unionAll` are aliasses of each other, both behave as a UNION ALL in SQL would. See: https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/reference/api/pyspark.sql.DataFrame.union.html

Comment: @ScootCork Yes you're right. I forgot about this and was thinking on `SQL` lines. Will have to do either of the two and then perform a `distinct()` operation. Thanks for highlighting.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can [anti join](https://spark.apache.org/docs/3.1.1/api/python/reference/api/pyspark.sql.DataFrame.join.html) `df` and `df2` and then union the result to `df2`. That way you have everything from `df2` and only the rows from `df` which are not in `df2`.

```
df3 = df.join(df2, on=['id'], how='anti').unionAll(df2)
print(df3.head(20))

[Row(id=0, value=0, calc=0), Row(id=7, value=7, calc=14), Row(id=6, value=6, calc=12), Row(id=5, value=5, calc=10), Row(id=1, value=1, calc=2), Row(id=3, value=3, calc=6), Row(id=8, value=8, calc=16), Row(id=2, value=2, calc=4), Row(id=4, value=4, calc=8), Row(id=9, value=9, calc=81), Row(id=10, value=10, calc=100)]
```